# How do I convert a vertical photo to wide format, similar to how video is done?

Tags: photo-editing, aspect-ratio

I've seen many vertical videos have a zoomed in, and blurred version of the video take the place of the vertical bars that would otherwise be present.

I would like to do the same thing with [something similar to this photo](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10101255310913770&set=pcb.10101255311233130&type=3&theater), so I can make it a profile picture.

The examples I know are for video, is there a reasonable way to do this for an unskilled person with a photo?

[image]

Comment: You can make the image a profile picture without stretching the image to fill some imaginary frame constraint that doesn't exist on Facebook. No one wants to see some CNN style blurred background on a Facebook image.

Comment: @dpollitt - Agreed.  I just used black bars... not terribly happy with it

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about graphic design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution lies in the screen capture you posted :)

1. Create a new document with the desired canvas size. (height should be the same as your original picture)
2. Import your picture in the document.
3. Copy the layer with the picture.
4. Blur the bottom layer
5. Stretch the bottom layer till if fills the whole canvas.

DONE! :)
You will end-up with something like this:
[image]

**EDIT:**
There would be also a second variant, to avoid stretching the bottom layer, after you blurred the bottom layer, you just cut it into to halves and move each half to the side of the upper (non blurred) layer.
It would then look something like this:

[image]

Comment: ahh, thanks! I'm much more of a programmer than a photo person.  Can you tell me what tools you used?  I'd also like to learn this since people might ask me ;)

Comment: I have used Photoshop, but practically ANY software capable of layers and blurring would be able to do this in a similar way.